# Materials used for damping

Tags: material-science, oscillators, dissipation

What type of material should be used for damping? Like my course says ductile materials but then if the damper is deformed it wont be able to be used again, so how does that work? Like why not stiff materials those that can resist deformation.

Comment: You should specify the frequency range over which you require damping.

Answer (score 0):

Ductility doesn't prohibit a material from being stiff.

Presumably, they would want a ductile material as compared to a brittle material because, under the worst case scenario of plastic deformations, it's better to have the damper become permanently deformed and still be able to accommodate a load, compared to fracture that could make it structurally useless.

I would assume that if the ductile material were deformed plastically outside of a safe range, it would still require replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Good acoustic damping requires 1) that the material used for damping is a good match to the characteristic impedance of free air (to minimize reflection) and 2) that material contains internal friction (to dissipate the energy contained in the incident sound waves).

The impedance of the absorptive material depends on its density and stiffness, and to match that of air requires that it be "fluffy" as opposed to hard and stiff.

Since impedance is a function of frequency, the requirements of the damping material will change over the full range of sound frequencies, so that in general, the absorptive material functions best over a certain range of frequencies and absorbs poorly outside of that range.